# Exercise 1.7.15 from Salamon's Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, borel-sets

This problem has three questions (a), (b) and (c). I've done most of them, with a little conclusion in (c) undone, which I've thought about it for a long time.

(c) Let $f: X\to Y$ be a Borel measurable linear operator from a Banach space $X$ to a separable normed vector space $Y$, prove that $f$ is continuous. Hint: $B=\\{x\in X: ||f(x)||_Y<\frac{1}{2}\\}$ is a nonmeagre Borel set.

I wonder how to show that $B$ is nonmeagre. My method is trying to show $B$ is open, and then use Baire Category Theorem. But I'm unable to show $B$ contains a ball. How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a sophisticated riddle.  $X=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb{N}, n>0} nB$.  A meager set is a countable union of nowhere-dense sets.  A countable union of meager sets is a countable union of countable unions of nowhere-dense sets, and assuming the axiom of countable choice - it is meager too.  So if $B$ were meager so would $X$.

Edit: You don't need the axiom of countable choice here.  If $B$ is covered by a countable union of nowhere-dense sets - you can scale the same cover to get a cover for $nB$.  Also, I neglected to mention it but you need to use the invariance of the topology to homothety of course.

Edit: I'm adding a photo of the exercise in case anyone is interested in what's discussed in the comments and can figure out why $Y$ needs to be separable.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually when I notice the hypothesis that $Y$ is separable, I wonder how this hypothesis works. So where do you use this fact？Is it useless?

Comment: @Matsuda:  This is not a complete solution to the problem.  Just the part you asked about - why $B$ is non-meager.  That part doesn't depend on $Y$ being separable.  Only that $f$ is linear, $Y$ is normed and $X$ is a complete metric space.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: One more question: I notice that my initial solution for (c) does not use the fact that $Y$ is separable, then I find some mistakes, hhh. Can you please tell me what to do next after I've showed that $B-B$ is a neighborhood of the origin (by Pettis's Lemma) in order to get the continuity of $f$?

Comment: @Matsuda:  I don't know how to solve the problem from the hint.  I'm sure that $B$ being Borel and non-meager does not depend on $Y$ being separable.  So separability of $Y$ is used after estabilishing the hint.   If I think of something I'll write.

Comment: @Matsuda:  I looked at the book.  If $B-B$ is a neighborhood of $0$ in $X$, then there's some $\epsilon>0$ such that given $\|x\| < \epsilon$ there are $y_0,y_1\in B$ such that $x=y_0-y_1$.  Then $\|f(x)\|\le \|f(y_0)\| + \|f(y_1)\| < 1$.  This shows $f$ maps the ball $B_X(0,\epsilon)$ into $B_Y(0,1)$, and from this it follows that $f$ is continuous.  Unless there's a mistake in exercise $1.7.5$ of the book, the separability of $Y$ is *not used*.  If this puzzles you, try e-mailing the [author](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/).

Comment: @Matsuda:  I think the author may have had another proof of the non-meagerness of $B$ in mind - and that is of covering $X$ with countably many translates $x_n+B$ of $B$ - and for doing this, use the separability of $Y$.  But it's not necessary.  Scaling a Banach space by $\lambda>0$ is a homeomorphism just like translating by $x$.

Comment: I appreciate it so much! I'll email the author for the question. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: I've emailed the author, and he agrees with your opinion. 'The separability of $Y$ does not seem to be needed.' Thanks for all your help.